# Cant access Contacts module (Odoo)

Tags: odoo

I am trying to access the Contacts module and I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
KeyError: 'followup.send'
```

Not sure what might be the issue, I tried searching the term followup.send in the open-source code of Odoo v14. But I was not able to find the term or figure out why this issue is occurring.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Best regards

Comment: Is there more than that little traceback?

Comment: return self.models[model_name] I am getting this error as well, But the strange thing is when I am trying to install the same modules on a different machine this error does not exist. Might some of the other databases be causing the error? I know this error pops up when there are circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried upgrade your contact module from apps list?
before doing this, try to run on trial database and see if it's works

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).